If the selected marbles have the same color, what is the probability that both marbles are blue?
There are 4 blue marbles and 5 red marbles and no other color in a box. Two marbles are
randomly selected from the box. If the selected marbles have the same color, what is the probability
that both marbles are blue?
This is the answer, but I can not understand why in denominator why it is not 2 out of 9.
P =  $$ \frac{ \binom{4}{2} } { \binom{4}{2} + \binom{5}{2} } $$  =  $$\frac{6}{6+10}$$ =  $$\frac{6}{16}$$ =  $$\frac{3}{8}$$

Because you are only interested in the case where the two marbles match.   It would be $\binom 92$ if the problem said "take two marbles uniformly at random, find the probability that they are both blue".

That is kind of Bayes' formula. You divide number of ways to choose 2 blue marbles by number of ways to choose 2 marbles of the same color (because we know that we are in situation of 2 of the same color, not just random 2).
Number of ways to choose 2 of same color is: choose 2 red or choose 2 blue. And that gives your answer.
